# Why pages are badly indexed? How to increase the presence of pages in the index? (index limits)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

The site has approximately 6,000 links to its pages (internal links). But only about 1000 are indexed. The site has a sitemap.xml and robots.txt files.

Found, not indexed 3200

Page crawled but not indexed yet 1200

[image: scr from google search console]

Why pages are badly indexed?

I read somewhere about index limits. or do i need to remake the site specifically for google search engine? Can't Google take over my blog service? There is a lot of text on the site.

How to increase the presence of pages in the index?

Comment: That's not a big number for Google to deal with. Those statuses are sometimes an indication of a quality trust issue with the content, causing Google to lose interest in processing the pages. Are there lots of thin or near duplicate pages?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath, The page is a copy. The canonical variant was not selected by the user 63 pgs, redirect 115

Comment: Having 1000 pages indexed is pretty good already.  Your site will get more indexed as the reputation of your site grows.  Almost no sites get 100% of their pages indexed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller. today blocked 2000+ pages with low content in robots.txt https://tbs-mbs.net/robots.txt I'll watch what will happen